# How to run cachefilesd in Yocto Linux

Tags: yocto

I run [bitbake core-image-minimal] to build a Yocto 1.5.
When run lsmod, there is no [cahefiles], [fscache] module.
I want build and run cachefilesd on my Yocto Linux.
How do run them.
Please help me.

Comment: Did you activate the kernel FSCACHE flag in the menuconfig ?

Comment: Yes, I did.
I activated all submenu of [Caches--->]. But when run [lsmod], Both module fscache and cachefiles did not show.